# How can I detect keyboard backspace key in NET.MAUI (both Android & iOS implementations)?

Tags: maui, custom-renderer

Migrating from Xamarin.Forms to NET.MAUI I need a custom entry control (custom renderer), in order to detect keyboard's backspace key event. I have four entries with 1 digit each (4 digits pins), and when the user focus on an empty text entry and presses backspace, I need to change focus in the previous digit. I used the following implementation in Xamarin.Forms, but I need to migrate in NET.MAUI.

**Android**

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace Test.Droid.CustomRenderer {
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer {

```
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {

    }

    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Del) {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Control.Text)) {
                    CustomEntry entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
                    entry.OnBackspacePressed();
                }
            }
        }
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

}

**iOS**

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace Test.iOS.CustomRenderers {

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer, IUITextFieldDelegate {

    IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e) {
        if (Element == null) {
            return;
        }

        var entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
        var textField = new UIBackwardsTextField();

        textField.EditingChanged += OnEditingChanged;
        textField.OnDeleteBackward += (sender, a) => {
            entry.OnBackspacePressed();
        };

        SetNativeControl(textField);

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    void OnEditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.TextProperty, Control.Text);
    }
}


public class UIBackwardsTextField : UITextField {
    // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
    public delegate void DeleteBackwardEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
    // elements of the list change.
    public event DeleteBackwardEventHandler OnDeleteBackward;


    public void OnDeleteBackwardPressed() {
        if (OnDeleteBackward != null) {
            OnDeleteBackward(null, null);
        }
    }

    public UIBackwardsTextField() {
        BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
        ClipsToBounds = true;
    }

    public override void DeleteBackward() {
        base.DeleteBackward();
        OnDeleteBackwardPressed();
    }
}
```

}

**And custom control**

namespace Test.CustomControls {

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry {
    public delegate void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event BackspaceEventHandler OnBackspace;

    public CustomEntry() { }

    public void OnBackspacePressed() {
        if (OnBackspace != null) {
            OnBackspace(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For migration from Xamarin to Maui, you may refer to [Upgrade from Xamarin to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/)

Comment: You could write a handler to replace custom renderer. This is an example for a [custom entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler#create-the-cross-platform-control).